# Amazon ECS doesn't output an image with two tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

In the ECR I have an image built with two tags:

[image]

When I try to obtain the tags via aws client, I don't seem to receive it.

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name=ir --region=us-east-1 --filter="tagStatus=TAGGED" --no-paginate | grep "v1.4.4"
```

I have tried everything I could think of, is there any reason why neither of the tags are returned? But I can see the image with both tags in the ECS:

[image]

Btw this seems to return though.

`aws ecr list-images --repository-name=ir --region=us-east-1 | grep "v1.4.4`
It's somehow related to tags...

Comment: Could you please provide the output your getting from these commands and why that is not the output you're expecting. I am not able to replicate your issue